# Recursive rename isn't working at all in batch

Tags: batch-file

So I have been searching in other topics how to rename files and folders in a .bat in a recursive way but it isn't working at all.

My code is:

```
@ echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /p rut="Introduce folder: "

FOR /D /R %%x in ("%rut%"\*) DO (

cd %rut%
echo %cd%
pause
ren .\* "a"

)

exit
```

But this only renames the files that are on the first folder and not in the rest. Forfile won't work at all with the variables.

What I want to get is how I could rename everything inside the main folder (including subfolders) whatever it is, be it files or folders as "a" to solve the Windows problem of having routes way too long when trying to delete a full structure, that is why I can't use the "*.txt" "*.whatever" solution.

A powershell solution would be valid too!

Thank you very much

**Edit** I added a random to see if it was the name that was conflicting but no, it is still not working:

```
ren .\* "a%RANDOM%"
```

And renaming them from cmd works the same way, I mean, if I write `ren "folder" "whatever"` it will change but in the script doesn't work with "*"

Comment: I do not see any recursive statement in your code, I expected  a call to the batch file in that loop

Comment: In the tutorials I searched they were all the same, just the for with /R which means "Recursive"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170838/discussion-between-spina97-and-mofi).

Comment: A PowerShell solution would consist of `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` and `Rename-Item`.

Comment: Put the root folder after the `/R` option rather including it in the set (that is the part in between `(`/`)` after `in`) -- see [`for /R`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)...

Comment: @Stephan those are there so I will know for sure that I am where I want to be since it was taking the root of the system as the start folder no matter the input

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thanks, I'll check it out when I have time!

Comment: @aschipfl Im sorry but I don't really get what you mean...

Comment: This is what I mean: `for /D /R "%rut%" %%x in (*) do ( ... )`

Comment: Unless you have at most 1 file in every folder, then your whole premise cannot possibly work. Only 1 file in any given folder can have the name "a".

Comment: I suppose that your `cd %rut%` command should be `cd "%%x"`. Anyway, the `for /?` help screen does _not_ mention that the `/R` switch means "Recursive"...

Comment: @Aacini that is why I searched it online, I mean sometimes there is an option that there is not on the /?

Comment: @dbenham yes, I do have only one on each folder

Comment: oh, alright, thanks @aschipfl